# What is the intuition behind discrete gaussian distribution for error sampling for lattice based crypto?

Tags: lattice-crypto

I'm still not sure why it has highest entropy (higher than uniform distribution).
What is the intuition of it?

Comment: If a discrete gaussian and a uniform distribution have the same variance, then discrete gaussian would mathematically have higher entropy.

Comment: Thanks! that's why gaussian is used in lattice based cryptosystem particularly homomorphic encryption. Homomorphic encryption has to manage encryption part with a bounded error term to ensure the correctness of decryption. The word "bounded" means that the error must be sampled from some specific range (defined by a variance). Based on variance, gaussian distribution is absolutely preferred!

Comment: @DannyNiu you said "mathematically", do you have some source of it?

Comment: It's mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Maximum_entropy) for continuous case, sources are cited by fellow Wikipedians. As for discrete case, I don't have known sources on hand, sorry.

Comment: For the discrete case, I laid it out as Lemma 3.21 of https://homepages.cwi.nl/~ducas/Thesis/thesis.pdf .